# Calling an Active directory authenticated web api using Ajax

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

I have deployed a Web API to Azure App service and I secured it with active directory authentication. I need to call this Web API On-Change of a field in my portal i.e. CRM Portal. (My CRM portal also allows only Active directory authenticated users to log in.) The way I have thought is I will do an Ajax call On-Change of the field to get the response. However I am unable to get the token itself. I am using adal.min.js as a library for supporting active directory authentication. I am easily able to get the response when calling a No Authentication Web API this way.

What should I be doing to get the response from an AD authenticated API from JQuery AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

> I have deployed a Web API to Azure App service and I secured it with active directory authentication.

AFAIK, you could use the OWIN middleware NuGet package [Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory) for AAD authentication, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet). Moreover, you could also leverage the built-in [authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) provided by Azure App Service to [Configure your App Service app to use Azure Active Directory login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication).

> What should I be doing to get the response from an AD authenticated API from JQuery AJAX call?

After you successfully logged in via ADAL.js, you could use the following code for acquiring the token and use it to access your web api endpoint.

```
authContext.acquireToken(authContext.config.clientId, function (error, token) {
    // Handle ADAL Error
    if (error || !token) {
        printErrorMessage('ADAL Error Occurred: ' + error);
        return;
    }

    // Get TodoList Data
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/TodoList",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        //TODO:
    });
});
```

Detailed code sample, you could follow [Azure AD Javascript Getting Started](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi).

You could just create a single AAD application and use it in your front-end and Web API backend. Also, you could create each AAD applications for your front-end and Web API backend, for this approach, you need to configure the `enpoints` property for resource mapping to instantiate ADAL AuthenticationContext, details you could follow [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).

Moreover, for the built-in App Service Authentication / Authorization, you could also leverage [How to Use the JavaScript client library for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library#auth) to authenticate users and retrieve the `mobileServiceAuthenticationToken`, then apply it to the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header when accessing your Web API endpoints.